# Rendering problem in qgis

Tags: qgis, python

I have fetch data from database and draw it on qgis 2.8 as vector layer it works fine with limited data but for large data it will not work and goes into not responding stage, I am unable to understand the problem. My code is follows

```
 layer =  QgsVectorLayer("Point?field=gid:integer&field=lattitude:double&
 field=longitude:double&field=depth:integer   
 &crs=EPSG:4326","items","memory")

 QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

 for i in range(len(Receivers)):
      # add a feature
      feature = QgsFeature()
      X = Receivers[i][1]
      Y = Receivers[i][2]
      temp=[] 
      #X= X cordinate  longitude
      #Y= Y cordinate  latitude

     feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(Y,X))) 

     length=len(Receivers[i])
     for j in range(0,length):                                    
           temp.append(Receivers[i][j])
     feature.setAttributes(temp)                                   
     layer.startEditing()
     layer.addFeature(feature, True)

     layer.commitChanges()                         
     layer.updateExtents()
```

Receiver list contain the data fetch from database (postgres)